# Can a noun be silent?

Tags: grammaticality

In the sentence: Don't be crazy.

Am I right to  say in the above sentence, the noun is the word 'you', which is not expressed  and so is silent.

So am I right to  say we can have a sentence without the noun being expressed and silent?

Comment: I generally use the term "elided", though I don't know if that's entirely correct.

Comment: No: If it were silent, then it would be written but not spoken. It is not written  and so is not silent. It is not even there.

Answer (score 3):

This would be a "*imperative sentence*"(An imperative sentence gives a direct command). And yes, imperative sentences can have implied subjects, you do not need to say "You" as the recipient of the command theoretically knows to whom the command is being directed.